# Tea tasting probability problem

Tags: probability

Ms. S claims that she can tell the difference between two tea brands. Hence it is organized an experiment where Ms. S tastes tea from ten cups. Brand A tea is in five cups and brand B tea is in five cups as well. Ms. S is asked to tell which five ones are of Brand A.

Find the probability that Ms. S tells at least three cups correctly at random, that is, we suppose that she chooses A-cups randomly.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please don't get the impression that the people here will solve your problems without any effort on your part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Total number of ways to choose 5 random cups is$\binom {10}5$.

Number of ways guessing 3 correct (cup A) and 2 wrong (cup B) is $\binom 53\cdot\binom 52$. Similarly for 4 cup A and 5 cup A, we get $\binom 54\cdot\binom51$ and $\binom 55\cdot\binom 50$.

Probability $=\frac{\binom53\binom52+\binom54\binom51+\binom55\binom50}{\binom{10}5}=\frac {100+25+1}{252}=\frac{126}{252}=\frac 12$.